# How to find second closest object in array in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm struggling with problem in Unity. I want to create a script that will be able to find the closest  object to the player (I managed to do it) and the second closest object to the player. My question is how to modify this code so that it also works for the second object?

```
public class Robot2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cameraHolder;
    public Transform[] objects;
    private Transform nearestObj;
    private Transform secondObj;
    void Update()
    {
        float lowestDist = Mathf.Infinity;
        nearestObj = null;
        secondObj = null;
    
        foreach(Transform obj in objects)
        {
            float dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, obj.position);
            if(dist < lowestDist)
            {
                lowestDist = dist;
                nearestObj = obj;
            }
        } 
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, nearestObj.transform.position, Color.red); 
        cameraHolder.transform.position = nearestObj.transform.position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ like the below code:

```
Objects.ToList().OrderBy(o => Vector3.Distance(transform.position, o.position))[1]
```

or

```
Objects.ToList().OrderByDescending(o => Vector3.Distance(transform.position, o.position))[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
float lowestDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
float nextLowestDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
nearestObject = null;
secondObject = null;

foreach ( Transform object in objects )
{
    float dist = Vector3.Distance( object.position, transform.position );
    if ( dist < lowestDistance )
    {
        if ( lowestDistance < nextLowestDistance )
        {
            nextLowestDistance = lowestDistance;
            secondObject = nearestObject;
        }
        lowestDistance = dist;
        nearestObject = object;
    }
    else if ( dist < nextLowestDistance )
    {
       nextLowestDistance = dist;
       secondObject = object;
    }
}
```